# slideToggle with two div's

Tags: jquery, html, css, show-hide, slidetoggle

I have little problem with the slidetoggle:
I have 2 divs :

```
<div class="slidingDiv"></div>
<div class="slidingDiv2"></div>
```

and 2 buttons :

```
<a href="#" class="show_hide2">Butt2</a>
<a href="#" class="show_hide">Butt1</a>
```

if I click on Butt1 it opens slidingDiv // ok
if I click again it close slidingDiv // ok

it's also working with Butt2

BUT, i want, if `slidingDiv` is already open, and if I click on `Butt2`, it opens `slidingDiv2` AND it close `slidingDiv`, and if `slidingDiv2` is already open, and if I click on `Butt1`, it opens `slidingDiv` AND it close `slidingDiv2`.

I think, I must use hasClass, removeClass and addClass but I don't know how to do

Thank's for your help

Yves

the code :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".slidingDiv").hide();
    $(".show_hide").show();

    $('.show_hide').click(function(){
        $(".slidingDiv").slideToggle();
    });

    $(".slidingDiv2").hide();
    $(".show_hide2").show();

    $('.show_hide2').click(function(){
         $(".slidingDiv2").slideToggle();
    });
});
```

Comment: please provide your html code too.

Comment: I thinks as per your requirement accordion is best please check this url http://jqueryui.com/accordion/

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
<a href="#" class="show_hide" data-target=".slidingDiv">Butt2</a>  
<a href="#" class="show_hide" data-target=".slidingDiv2">Butt1</a>

<div class="slidingDiv slider">slidingDiv</div>
<div class="slidingDiv2 slider">slidingDiv</div>
```

then

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    //all target div's which has to be toggled has the class slider
    var $sliders = $(".slider").hide();
    //all anchors which has to trigger the slide has the class show_hide and has a data-* property data-target whose value is the selector to find the target div
    $(".show_hide").show();

    $('.show_hide').click(function () {
        var $target = $($(this).data('target'));
        $sliders.not($target).stop(true, true).slideUp();
        $target.stop(true, true).slideToggle();
    });
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/D4Eys/)

Answer (score 1):

You can try to do something like this. One button which Toggle two different divs at once. Just as starting point you should have one of them hidden and another one visible.

```
$('.show_hide').click(function(){
    $(".slidingDiv").slideToggle();
    $(".slidingDiv2").slideToggle();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $(".slidingDiv").hide();
    $(".show_hide").show();

    $('.show_hide').click(function(){
       $(".slidingDiv").slideToggle();
       $(".slidingDiv2").slideUp(); // add this line
    });


    $(".slidingDiv2").hide();
    $(".show_hide2").show();

    $('.show_hide2').click(function(){
       $(".slidingDiv2").slideToggle();
       $(".slidingDiv").slideUp(); // and this line
    });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

See this demo fiddle: **http://jsfiddle.net/u6jB8/**

*Markup*:

```
<div class="wrap">
    <a href="#" class="show_hide">Butt2</a>
    <div class="slidingDiv">div 1</div>
</div>

<div class="wrap">
    <a href="#" class="show_hide">Butt1</a>
    <div class="slidingDiv">div 2</div>
</div>
```

*JQuery*:

```
$('a.show_hide').on("click", function() {
    /* stop currently running animation if any, and hide all divs */
    $('div.slidingDiv').stop().slideUp('fast');

    /* stop currently running animation if any, and toggle corresponding div */
    $(this).next('div.slidingDiv').stop().slideToggle('fast');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/Es32W/1/

```
HTML :
-----------------------------------------
<input type="button" value="Slide1" class="slide1">
<input type="button" value="Slide2" class="slide2">
<div class="slideDiv1 aa">Slide 1</div>
<div class="slideDiv2 noDisplay">Slide 2</div>

JQuery :
------------------------------------------

$( document ).ready(function() {

$(".slide1").click(function(){    
    if($(".slideDiv1").hasClass("noDisplay")){
       $(".slideDiv1").removeClass("noDisplay").show("slide");
       $(".slideDiv2").addClass("noDisplay").hide("slide");       
    }    
  });

$(".slide2").click(function(){    
    if($(".slideDiv2").hasClass("noDisplay")){
       $(".slideDiv2").removeClass("noDisplay").show("slide") ;
       $(".slideDiv1").addClass("noDisplay").hide("slide");       
    }

  });
});

CSS
---------------------------------------------
.slideDiv1, .slideDiv2 {
    width:200px; height:200px; color:#fff;
}

.slideDiv1 {
    background-color:red;
}

.slideDiv2 {
    background-color:blue; display:none;
}
/*.noDisplay { display:none; }*/
```